# Правильно спроектировать бд

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу добавить спецификации для обьявлений,начал проектировать структуру базы. И столкнулся с проблемой. Вот есть название характеристик, и их значения. Допустим у нас есть характеристика `страна производителя` и под нее заводятся значения характеристики с типом `string`, но если характеристика `наличие камеры`, то для нее значение должно быть с типом `boolean`. Вот как правильно спроэктировать тут таблицу?

Comment: `наличие камеры` - это сущность что ли ?

Comment: Если вы хотите иметь произвольные атрибуты (пополняемые в рантайме) у объектов - смотрите в сторону модели Entity-Attribute-Value.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator ну да.

Comment: @Nofate мне предлогали использовать данный патерн, но я не могу найти примера для реляционных бд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите иметь произвольные атрибуты (пополняемые в рантайме) у объектов - смотрите в сторону модели [Entity-Attribute-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

<sub>Привожу пример для MariaDB</sub>

Отдельно создается словарь атрибутов, в вашем случае с указанием типов.

```
CREATE TABLE Attributes (
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  type enum('string', 'bool') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Допустим, сами объекты, для которых мы храним атрибуты лежат в таблице `Objects`

```
CREATE TABLE Objects (
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
-- ...
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Тогда можно сложить значения атрибутов в таблицу следующего вида:

```
CREATE TABLE AttributeValues (
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  attributeId int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  objectId int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  stringValue varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  boolValue bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY objectId (objectId)
);
```

Когда вы будете вытаскивать данные из БД, в зависимости от типа атрибута смотрите либо в поле `stringValue` либо в `boolValue`.

---

Пример данных, для вашего случая:

```
INSERT INTO Objects (...) VALUES (...);

INSERT INTO Attributes (id, name, type) VALUES (1, 'страна производителя', 'string');
INSERT INTO Attributes (id, name, type) VALUES (2, 'наличие камеры', 'bool');

INSERT INTO AttributeValues (attributeId, objectId, stringValue) VALUES (1, 1, 'Россия');
INSERT INTO AttributeValues (attributeId, objectId, boolValue) VALUES (2, 1, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

AS это всего лишь один из вариантов, в качестве иллюстрации.

Для начала определите скоп основных(общих) параметров, какие могут быть у объектов.

Эти параметры имеет смысл внести в основную таблицу.

Потом смотрим, какие из параметров на самом деле сами являются достаточно сложными объектами. Например камера - нам ведь нужно знать не ее наличие, как факт, а количество мегапикселей, фокусное расстояние. Может их вообще несколько.

Для каждого такого параметра создаем отдельную таблицу, связанную по ключу с основной.

Все остальные, опциональные, параметры вынести в отдельную таблицу.

Допустим вам надо хранить информацию о смартфонах. Что у них у всех общего?

1. Диагональ экрана.
2. Производитель
3. Операционная система (ios, android, winmobile, ...)
4. Версия операционной системы
5. Объем внутренней памяти

и т.д.

Соответственно делаем таблицу

```
CRAETE TABLE phones (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, --сделать первичным ключем
    vendor VARCHAR(100),
    os VARCHAR(100),
    os_v_major SMALLINT,
    os_v_minor SMALLINT,
    ram INT,
    ....
)
```

Таблица описания камеры

```
CREATE TABLE camera(
    id_phone INT, --внешний ключ в таблицу phones
    type VARCHAR(10), --front/back/... что за камера, спереди/сзади
    focus INT,
    pixels INT,
    ....
)
```

Для уникальных параметров, которые могут быть, а могут и не быть, создаем такую таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE params(
    id_phone INT, --внешний ключ в таблицу phones
    name VARCHAR(100), --имя параметра
    value VARCHAR(100) --значение параметра
)
```